# c++ multi thread object out of scope

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm starting a worker thread (written inside a new class) from a UI event (seperate class). Now as the new worker thread is created from main UI thread, it is immediately returning from the control, which causing the worker thread class object to be destroyed. Better explanation can be found by checking below code.

```
//class - UI  
void CUIClass::button_click()
{
  CDataProcess obj;
  obj.Start();
}

//class - DataProcess
CDataProcess::CDataProcess()
{
}

CDataProcess::~CDataProcess()
{
}

void CDataProcess::Start()
{
  CWinThread *pThread = AfxBeginThread(DataProcessingThread, this);
}

UINT CDataProcess::DataProcessingThread()
{
  //some processing
}
```

Now some of the possible solutions I thought about are:

- Make 'CDataProcess obj;' a member of UI class so it doesn't get out of scope. But I kept it locally purposefully.
- Use WaitForSignleObject inside UI class button_event() to wait for worker thread completion signal or write a waiting function inside worker class.

What else could be the proper solution?

Comment: It is your responsibility to ensure that `CDataProcess` instance outlives the thread. Having it as a local variable makes no sense. Whatever purpose you had in mind when you "kept it local", you would have to rethink it. Blocking the UI thread until the worker thread finishes completely defeats the purpose of having the worker thread in the first place; if you are willing to do that (and have the UI freeze), just do that same work on the UI thread to begin with.

Comment: You can use `::WaitForSingleObject(pThread->m_hThread, INFINITE);` for wait your working thread in main thread.

Comment: OT: Unless you need something specific from MFC you can always use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) which VS2013 supports

Comment: No. I'm only with MFC threads.

Comment: Can you provide code where you call `Start()` ?

Comment: As posted in the original snippet. Its called (one time, then UI will be blocked) from a UI element event.

Comment: @PLearner sorry, I not noticed. Now I think that your first approach with `CDataProcess obj;` member is better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Well , if you are going to open a thread for each click on the button (which I think you need to reconsider) , a Thread pool is most suitable here.
basically , you want to write your onClick logic in one function (that may call other functions and objects , surely) which will be the callback function for the onClick event. then you ask your thread pool to execute the callback asynchrounosly.

you may also want to read about `std::async` which launches functions asynchrounosly , but keep in mind that if your thread is heavy , you might want to go with a thread pool anyway.

Comment: then make the thread a member variable of the button, or better, create a class that manages a thread , and a button will contain it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I have created some serious trouble for me. I should stick to DataProcess functionality inside a seperate class which can be called from a thread started by UI class. That way it solves every single issues.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. Obviousely, you need to create a worker object that lives longer than `button_click` callback:

```
CDataProcess* obj = new CDataProcess();
obj->Start();
```

Assuming by name `AfxBeginThread`, you're in Windows (more specific, MFC) environment. You can use any of "task pooling" techniques (once again, depends on what you're trying to achieve). Connection points, thread pools -- you name it. How you need to detect when a task is finished? How to show it to a user? Will you allow a user to cancel a task? etc, etc.

Comment: then the function ends , obj gets out of scope and you have a memory leak. aside than not be able to terminate the created thread in any way

Comment: For sure you have to track this object further on. How? Basically depends on your threading model.
I cannot recommend, but what you can do is 
delete this

Anyways, if you need an object that lives longer than {} scope, it is up to you to manage it.

Comment: you never do `delete this`! this is a dangerous practice!

Comment: @DavidHaim you can absolutely do `delete this`, how do you think reference counted objects are implemented?

Comment: @Mgetz rules have this nasty habit of having exceptions. Yes, you technically can `delete this`, but you have to do it with the utmost care. You have to do it even more carefully than using raw `new` and `delete`. "You *should* never `delete this`" would perhaps be better.

Comment: @Mgetz defenitly not with `delete this`.

Comment: Well, it depends. The standard allows this operation. 
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-zero

Once again, I recommend reading through threading chapter of Programming Server-Side Applications for Microsoft Windows 2000. May "Server-Side" don't frighten you, but it covers quite some techniques on dealing with how you can treat threads. MFC introduces something on top of that as well, but knowing the core is a must.

Comment: @DavidHaim A random finding: [here, at line 123](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01078.html). Sorry for bursting your bubble.